# How do I schedule a weekly redirect?

Tags: redirect, drupal

I'm probably explaining this badly.

At my college we will be hosting virtual open events.

We want to show at the same URL holding content that at a certain time every week, is replaced by the virtual open event as it goes live.

Then two hours later, the virtual open event will end and the holding content will replace it.

Is there a way to do this on a schedule without managing it manually?

If it helps, I'm using Drupal.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7 or Drupal 8? There are modules that control publishing status, based on time/date, i.e. https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler Another option is to have a content type with open and close date. Then create a View that gets that content based on the dates. And if no content is available, then the View shows some default content.

Comment: Look into redirect module and schedule module